How to dynamically load libraries (more than one)?
Currently, due to the needs of my project, I am loading the libraries dynamically and the first time I load them I get errors and not all the graphics work.
I don't know how to correct the load so that it works correctly and I don't know the cause of why it fails.
Here is an image of the errors:

The libraries are loaded correctly, as far as I understand:

The js code I use to load the libraries is
for ( var i = 0; i < librerias.length; i++ ) {
    var rutaLibreria = librerias[ i ];
    //console.log( "Ruta de la librería:", rutaLibreria );

    var fechaActual = new Date();
    let timestamp = fechaActual.getTime();

    let fechaFormateada = new Date( timestamp ).toISOString().replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' );

    if (loadedCount === librerias.length) { 
        if ( !isScriptLoaded( rutaLibreria ) ) {
            console.log("Carganddo la ULTIMA libreria...");
            script = document.createElement( 'script' );
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = `${rutaLibreria}?${fechaFormateada}`;
            script.onload = function () {
                Highcharts.chart( container, config );
            };
            document.head.appendChild( script );
        }
    }else{
        loadedCount++;
        console.log("Carganddo SOLO la libreria...");
        if ( !isScriptLoaded( rutaLibreria ) ) {
            script = document.createElement( 'script' );
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = `${rutaLibreria}?${fechaFormateada}`;
            document.head.appendChild( script );
        }

    } 
}

If someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.
What I'm trying to do is to do a dynamic library loading along with the graph configuration, so I can draw any graph as needed.
Added Detail

Indeed, I think it would not be possible to replicate. I will try to leave more details.
The js code that I left is the one that loads the js libraries (librerias) in the header. the libraries arrive like this:
["https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"]

and the chart configuration (config) like this:
{"chart":{"type":"line"},"title":{"text":"Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016"},"subtitle":{"text":"Source= thesolarfoundation.com"},"yAxis":{"title":{"text":"Number of Employees"}},"xAxis":{"accessibility":{"rangeDescription":"Range= 2010 to 2017"}},"legend":{"layout":"vertical","align":"right","verticalAlign":"middle"},"plotOptions":{"series":{"label":{"connectorAllowed":false},"pointStart":2010}},"series":[{"name":"Installation","data":[43934,52503,57177,69658,97031,119931,137133,154175]},{"name":"Manufacturing","data":[24916,24064,29742,29851,32490,30282,38121,40434]},{"name":"Sales & Distribution","data":[11744,17722,16005,19771,20185,24377,32147,39387]},{"name":"Project Development","data":[0,0,7988,12169,15112,22452,34400,34227]},{"name":"Other","data":[12908,5948,8105,11248,8989,11816,18274,18111]}],"responsive":{"rules":[{"condition":{"maxWidth":500},"chartOptions":{"legend":{"layout":"horizontal","align":"center","verticalAlign":"bottom"}}}]}}

and when I run the graph like this:
Highcharts.chart(container, config );


Could you share some more details about your project config and how do you import the Highcharts? It would be the best if you could reproduce this problem in a jsfiddle, but in your situation I imagine that's not possible. Example demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0pbeym97/

Adding detail to my question. Since I need to add the libraries dynamically, the first load gives me those errors, but if I do a refresh, it seems to load well. I don't understand why if I add the libraries in the header, it doesn't take them.

Are you using any framework that could impact the libraries loading order? Also if you're using asynchronous loading, ensure that you're waiting for each script to load before proceeding. You can use async and await or promise chaining to manage this.

When loading for the first time, errors appear when looking at the console and it does not load the additional libraries in the graph, such as the download menu of the graph in the image. In the case of a 3D pie chart, the first load is done in 2D and if I refresh it just loads the 3D. This is because it does not recognize the libraries that were left in the head.
in the code I tried using promises.
I leave the demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/rodo_Chile/buyoq9da/2/

The isScriptLoaded function checks if the script URL is present in the head.innerHTML, which might not work great in all cases. Instead try checking if script tag exists by using document.querySelector. Here's working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7h5g1ym9/

It doesn't work. If you look closely, the menu to download the graphic doesn't appear on the first load, because it gives an error with the libraries. If you run (F12) you can see the errors in the console when loading or when the libraries are not found loaded. I don't understand why this happens, if the libraries are in the head or how to force them to be loaded. :(

I checked my demo one more time, and the exporting menu icon appears on the first load, also there are no errors in the console. Are you checking the demo I sent in the last comment?

I developed a component that attaches to projects (User Control for GeneXus) so that the developer can add his charts as needed. For this reason, I need to dynamically load JS libraries and the code provided ensures that these libraries are loaded, because I was getting errors and it is because the libraries were not loaded correctly. Basically, the code provided ensures that the libraries are loaded before invoking HighChart. I have everything working fine with the following code. The libraries have a list of dependencies in json format.
función loadScripts(url) {
return new Promise((resolver, rechazar) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = resolver;
    script.onerror = rechazar;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
})
}
función asincrónica loadHighcharts(lib)   {
Try {
    para(const url of lib) {
        si(!isScriptLoaded(url)) {
            esperar loadScripts(url);
        }
    }
    Cargar($CONFIG);
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al cargar las librerías de Highcharts:", error);
}
}
función isScriptLoaded(url) {
var headContent = document.head.innerHTML;
return headContent.includes(url);
}
Función Cargar(configuración) {
let json = gx.json.evalJSON(config);
Highcharts.chart($ID, json);
}
window.onload = loadHighcharts(librerías);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
